# Explanation of "in" in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, web-services, web-applications, web

Please, consider the code sample below, and focus on variable assignments. Since I have never seen such form in C++, what does the following mean: "upload" **in** new XMLHttpRequest`.

I would need a good explanation of what does the following statement mean: `progress: "upload" in new XMLHttpRequest`. Especially, the `in` is not in C++ present. What is that **`in`** supposed to do?

```
tests = {
  filereader: typeof FileReader != 'undefined',
  dnd: 'draggable' in document.createElement('span'),
  formdata: !!window.FormData,
  progress: "upload" in new XMLHttpRequest
};
```

thank you.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in

Comment: @Dennis: +1, Hi Dennis. Complete answer is within that link. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Chapter 11.8.7 - The `in` operator](http://es5.github.com/#x11.8.7) says

> Return the result of calling the *[[HasProperty]]* internal method of *rval* with argument *ToString(lval)*.

which means that

```
(lval in rval)
```

is true when `rval` is an object and it has a property named `String(lval)`.

`in` is also used in `for (... in ...)` loops but that is just similar syntax, not a use of this operator.

---

> ```
> "upload" in new XMLHttpRequest
> ```

This is asking "does an `XMLHttpRequest` instance have a property named 'upload'?"  It's effectively checking whether this browser has a particular feature which might not be present on all browsers.

`upload` in particular is specified in [XMLHttpRequest Level 2](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-upload-attribute) as an object that [supports certain event handler](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#xmlhttprequesteventtarget) to let you monitor the progress of an upload:

> ```
> interface XMLHttpRequestEventTarget : EventTarget {
>   // event handlers
>   [TreatNonCallableAsNull] attribute Function? onloadstart;
>   [TreatNonCallableAsNull] attribute Function? onprogress;
>   [TreatNonCallableAsNull] attribute Function? onabort;
>   [TreatNonCallableAsNull] attribute Function? onerror;
>   [TreatNonCallableAsNull] attribute Function? onload;
>   [TreatNonCallableAsNull] attribute Function? ontimeout;
>   [TreatNonCallableAsNull] attribute Function? onloadend;
> };
> ```

Comment: Hi Mike. +1, thank you for your answer. In my opinion, this is the best answer and I am marking it as the *Recommended Answer*

Answer (score 3):

The statement `'draggable' in document.createElement('span')` returns a boolean. It checks to weather or not the element (in this case a span) has the `draggable` property, if it does `true` is returned, if it doesn't the return value will be false. There's nothing more to it.

If you see code like this:

```
for (varName in obj)
{
    //some stuff
}
```

All you really are seeing is a loop over the enumerable properties of the object (`obj`). Assume an object that looks like this:

```
var obj = {foo:'bar',non:'sense'};
```

Then `varName` will be equal to `foo`, then `non` etc... in other words: the "`x in y` statement"s main goal is to check the existence of enumerable (public) properties of an object

Comment: +1, thank you Elias for your detailed answer. Great explanation and additional information. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Bunkai.Satori: Happy to help, a friendly word of warning, though. I noticed you said there are many similarities between C++ and JS, There is one important (really important) difference, though: C++ is OO, JS is _functional_ (like lisp and scheme, for example). The similarities end when you try to apply the same logic you know from C++ to JS pretty soon. JS is, essentially, a lot _LESS_ similar than it seems at first glance

Comment: I see.. thank you for this warning. I see JavaScript as limited C++. C++ can be used for Procedural programming, although, you are correct, it is mostly used for OO programming. On the other hand, JS has possibility of creating objects, but those are a kind of very limited objects or maybe instances of functions. I agree with you that JS and C++ have many differences.

Comment: JavaScript *is* object-oriented, it just uses prototypes instead of classes.

Comment: @Dennis: JavaScript was, in its infancy, supposed to be _functional_. To make the language feel more familiar, it became the  multi-paradigm language we know today. To say it's OO doesn't hold water IMHO. It has an Object model, sure, but it lends itself to Scheme/Lisp-style programming, too. In many cases I find the functional approach is to be preferred over OO constructions. That is, of course a personal thing. However: JS doesn't support true OO data-hiding concepts, for that, you'll have to turn to functional techniques (lambda functions-> closures)

Answer (score 2):

- `typeof FileReader != 'undefined'`

  - **true** if an object named *FileReader* exists, **false** otherwise
- `'draggable' in document.createElement('span')`

  - **true** if *<span>* element allows the *draggable* property/method, **false** otherwise
- `!!window.FormData`

  - **true** if *window* object has a property/method with the name *FormData*, **false** otherwise
- `"upload" in new XMLHttpRequest`

  - **true** if *XMLHttpRequest* object has a property/method with the name *upload*, **false** otherwise

Comment: +1, Hi and thank you for the answer and the additional information. This answer is my candidate #2 for the accepted answer. I received explanation of all the lines in the code sample.

Answer (score 1):

`'x' in y` will return true if "y" contains a property named "x"

By the way, you shouldn't expect Javascript and C++ to be so similar. They are quite different.

Comment: +1, Hi Billy. Yes, I found already that JavaScript and C++ are different languages. However, many things are still similar. Knowledge of C++ helps me to understand JavaScript quickier. Btw, thank you for your correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
tests = {
  filereader: typeof FileReader != 'undefined',
  dnd: 'draggable' in document.createElement('span'),// Basically checks the draggable property of span
  formdata: !!window.FormData,
  progress: "upload" in new XMLHttpRequest// checking for the upload property of XMLHttpRequest/, you can add an eventlistner to check the progress event. 
};
```

As far as "in" goes it is nothing but checking if the element is present .It returns a boolean value